# Series - Mary learned 20 new French wordds on January 1, 24 on January 2,

Tags: sequences-and-series

Mary learned 20 new French wordds on January 1, 24 on January 2, 28 on January 3, and so on, through January 31. How many words has she learned during January.

My solution is 2480. Could someone check if this is right?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Can you explain how you got that answer?

Comment: I did find the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

That is correct. There are several ways to think about the solution, but one is as follows:

S = 20 + 24 + 28 ... + 140

S = 20 + (20+4) + (20+8) + ... + (20+120)

S = 20 + 4(1 + 2 + 3 ... + 30) + 20*30

S = 20 + 4[30(30+1)/2] + 600

S = 620 + 60(31)

S = 2480